# Looking to quantity of item to index in List<> c#

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I am looking to a quantity to an item I am adding to a List<> in C#, but every time I add a item the quantity for the entire List changes? Any help would be great.

```
private void btnAddBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product NewItem = new Product();

    foreach (Product tmp in tmpProducts)
    {
        NewItem.Stock = tmp.Stock;
        tmp.Quantity = NewItem.Quantity;
    }
    NewItem.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text);

    if (NewItem.Quantity > 0)
    {
        if (NewItem.Quantity > NewItem.Stock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is only = " + NewItem.Stock + " in stock");
        }
        else
        {
            shoppingCart.Add(tmpProducts.ElementAt(lstViewProducts.SelectedIndex));
            LoadCart();
            txtQuantity.Text = "0";
        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter quantity you want");
}
```

Comment: Put the initilization of the `Product` into the loop, otherwise you are only using one object:

Comment: By the way, you should use `uint.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt16`. If the user enters a non-numeric string, your application will crash.

Comment: Why are you assign Stock in loop? Ultimately It will assign last Products Stock in your tmpProducts collection.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `tmp.Quantity = NewItem.Quantity;` . Its reset products in your list.

```
private void btnAddBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product NewItem = new Product();

    foreach (Product tmp in tmpProducts)
    {           
        NewItem.Stock = tmp.Stock;
    }

    NewItem.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text);

    if (NewItem.Quantity > 0)
    {
        if (NewItem.Quantity > NewItem.Stock)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is only = " + NewItem.Stock + " in stock");
        }
        else
        {
            shoppingCart.Add(tmpProducts.ElementAt(lstViewProducts.SelectedIndex));
            LoadCart();
            txtQuantity.Text = "0";
        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter quantity you want");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, but it now sets the quantity to 0 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is quite simple:

You are creating exactly one instance of a Product which is called "NewItem" and you use only this item for everything.

Example:

```
foreach (Product tmp in tmpProducts)
{           
    NewItem.Stock = tmp.Stock;
}
```

You are iterating all items of the list and assign their values to NewItem.Stock. NewItem.Stock will have only the value of the last item of the list. If there is no item in the list, NewItem.Stock will keep it's inital value. This loop looks kinda weird.

The answer to your original Question: 
It must be a problem with references. Makes sure the Products in the List are not all the same reference. I'll show you some code:

Correct (instanciating new Object and having extra references):

```
Product x = new Product ("abc"); // create new object with new reference
list.add(x);
x = new Product ("def");  // create new object with new reference
list.add(x);
```

Wrong (no use of the "new"-keyword to specify new references)

```
Product x = new Product ("abc"); // create new object with new reference
list.add(x);
x.Name = "def";  // keep the reference (no "new" keyword") and change it
list.add(x);
```

If you do not use the new keyword, you will always talk to the same object. If you then change something on this object all refences to this object still point to the object and a access to internal varaibles will always show the same result.

... and btw: better replace "NewItem.Quantity > 0" by a Property which is called "Available" and returns "NewItem.Quantity > 0". This gives you a way better reusability.